# Using Apollo GraphQL HOC pattern with an existing HOC

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, higher-order-components

I have a basic HOC which sits around a few of my components:

```
import * as React from 'react';    
export const AuthRoute = () => (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  return class extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {
      super(props);
    }
    public render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

I want this HOC to be able to access another HOC - the React Apollo client HOC for GraphQL. I've tried using Apollo client on this HOC but it's giving an error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined". Here's my attempt:

```
const AuthRoute = () => (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  return class extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {
      super(props);
    }
    public render() {

      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

const GET_AUTH = gql`
  {
    authStatus {
      authStatus
    }
  }
`;

export default compose(graphql(GET_AUTH))(AuthRoute);
```

Am I missing something simple here because I thought this would work? Or is there a better practice to a HOC based library like Apollo with an existing HOC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've just got a typo.  Change your default export to this:

`export default compose(graphql(GET_AUTH), AuthRoute);`

...and it should work